# Group a groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi all so I have the following column in my dataframe:

```
     LC_REF
1   DT 16 2C
2   DT 16 2C
3   DT 16 2C

1    DT 16 3C
6    DT 16 3C
3    DT 16 3C
7    DT 16 3C

0    DT 17 1C
0    DT 17 1C
0    DT 17 1C
1    DT 17 1C

0    DT 17 2C
2    DT 17 2C
4    DT 17 2C
5    DT 17 2C

4   DT 17 3C
1   DT 17 3C
8   DT 17 3C
```

And I'm wondering if its possible to organize every group of LC_REF's such that the index is in ascending order:

```
     LC_REF
1   DT 16 2C
2   DT 16 2C
3   DT 16 2C

1    DT 16 3C
3    DT 16 3C
6    DT 16 3C
7    DT 16 3C

0    DT 17 1C
0    DT 17 1C
0    DT 17 1C
1    DT 17 1C

0    DT 17 2C
2    DT 17 2C
4    DT 17 2C
5    DT 17 2C

1   DT 17 3C
4   DT 17 3C
8   DT 17 3C
```

so far I have tried:

```
 df.groupby('LC_REF').apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_index,'LC_REF',1)
 grouped = df.groupby('LC_REF').sum().reset_index()
```

but that does not give the correct output.

Comment: `reset_index` and `sort_values`

Comment: seems like I was trying to over complicate it using a groupby

Answer (score 3):

I think better is use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from `index`, then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().sort_values(['LC_REF','index']).set_index('index').rename_axis(None)
print (df)
     LC_REF
1  DT 16 2C
2  DT 16 2C
3  DT 16 2C
1  DT 16 3C
3  DT 16 3C
6  DT 16 3C
7  DT 16 3C
0  DT 17 1C
0  DT 17 1C
0  DT 17 1C
1  DT 17 1C
0  DT 17 2C
2  DT 17 2C
4  DT 17 2C
5  DT 17 2C
1  DT 17 3C
4  DT 17 3C
8  DT 17 3C
```

Comment: @jezrael looks like i was doign too much w groupby, i just needed to sort_values... seems obvious in hindsight

Comment: @codeninja - I think `groupby` is here first idea, so no problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_table(StringIO("""
id   LC_REF
1   DT 16 2C
2   DT 16 2C
3   DT 16 2C
1    DT 16 3C
6    DT 16 3C
3    DT 16 3C
7    DT 16 3C
0    DT 17 1C
0    DT 17 1C
0    DT 17 1C
1    DT 17 1C
0    DT 17 2C
2    DT 17 2C
4    DT 17 2C
5    DT 17 2C
4   DT 17 3C
1   DT 17 3C
8   DT 17 3C"""), sep = '   ')

df.sort_values(['LC_REF', 'id'],ascending=True)
```

Comment: where is the column id came from ?

Comment: @Wen, I named the column id, which has been shown as the index

Answer (score 0):

Or As my comment , that is the 1st good way to go . But if you you do want to using `groupby` try this

```
df.groupby('LC_REF',as_index=False).apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_index)
```